# subview of IKImageView appears below image instead of above

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsimageview, ikimageview

I have a `IKImageView` and a `NSImageView` as a subview. Subviews are supposed to get drawn above their master view. I tried an `NSImageView` with the same subview, and it worked fine, but I really need to be able to move the image around with the mouse, and zoom it with a slider, and I think `IKImageView` is a bit easier.

What happens is this:
[image: img 1]
As you can see, the small picture (subview) is below the image on the `IKImageView`, but in front of the background of `IKImageView`.
How can I fix this?

ps: Do you think I should use NSImageView? If so, how would I move it around, and zoom?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call `addSubview` again everytime after I set the IKImageView's image.

That work for me.

Comment: i ended up subclassing NSImageView. i forgot to update the question when i figured it out.